# Uniform Convergence and Equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading the proof that is $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent then $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous [here](http://math.mit.edu/~rbm/18.100B/Ascoli-Arzela.pdf)

at the bottom on page 1. 
I understand everything in the proof except when he writes for $j \leq N$ the function $f_j$ is uniformly continuous. What is the justification for this?

Answer (score 1):

A finite collection of uniformly continuous functions is always equicontinuous.  Can you see why?

Comment: That's not my question. I want to know why they are uniformly continuous in the first place.

Comment: Is the space you are working on compact?  If it is, any continuous function is uniformly continuous.  That is the stated assumption on the PDF you linked above.

Comment: Ok, missed that, thanks.